# syntax error for change replication

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication

On a mysql 5.7 master, the following command generates syntax error.

```
CHANGE REPLICATION FILTER REPLICATE_DO_DB = ('mydb')
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REPLICATION FILTER REPLICATE_DO_DB = ('mydb')' at line 1
```

I have tried it with or without single quote around database name. [official guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/change-replication-filter.html)

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ I tried it with or without quote.

Answer (score 1):

CHANGE REPLICATION FILTER REPLICATE-DO-DB is a **SLAVE** filter to read only (mydb) from the relay log.

If you want to filter the Master to write only (mydb) statements on the binary logs (and replicate only (mydb) to all slaves), you need to use the `--binlog-do-db=name` variable ([Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-do-db)) on master server.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is pointing at the word `REPLICATION`, so the problem is there or immediately before there.  It is not about quoting the db name.

This feature was added in 5.7; what version are you running?

This command applies only to Slaves.

This command cannot be used with Group Replication.

Answer (score 0):

For versions below 5.7 it seems the value can be set as command line parameter only. For example:

```
mysqld --replicate-do-do=mydb
```

https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/refman-5.6-en.pdf